# Thymeleaf iterate data in table for different variable name java

Tags: java, xml, html-table, thymeleaf

My data from xml file is  qualMap={i201601_psv=400, i201601_pgsv=2500, i201602_psv=500, i201602_pgsv=2600}. Note that i have psv and pgsv for 201601 and 201602. But my variable name is different. Currently i am using this code

```
<block th:each="incPDate: ${incParticipant}">
            <td rowspan="3" th:text="${incPDate.dataMap.i201601_psv}"></td>
            <td rowspan="3" th:text="${incPDate.dataMap.i201601_pgsv}"></td>
            <td rowspan="3" th:text="${incPDate.dataMap.i201601_circle}"></td>
            </block>
```

However my code above will only display psv and pgsv for date 201601 as I specified {incPDate.dataMap.i201601_pgsv}, to display another I have to specify again {incPDate.dataMap.i201602_pgsv}. Imagine if I have record for 10 months.How can I define all for variable with different name.Any incremental of variable can be work on such as  fragment parameter? I wanted to display table as below

[image]

I am new to thymeleaf. plase give me some example code . any help would be appreciated

Comment: Sorry, the sentence _"However this is manually define all the variable name"_ doesn't make sense in English. Please try to clarify what you are asking.

Comment: one approach can be to get the data into a map with date as 'key' vs object {psv, pgsv}. Iterate this map in thymeleaf to get the required result.

Comment: @AbhishekAgarwal, other than changing the data structure. anything to explore in Thymeleaf? such as <th:with> or <th:include> to be work on this? seems like i need to use javascript to concatenate between subString for date increment?